# displaying database column data horizontally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a scenario in which I have to show data of each table field horizontally.

```
ID    1 2 3 4 5

Name  'Ahmad' 'Umar' 'Nadeem' 'Raza' 'Saquib'

City  'New York' 'Paris' 'London' 'New York' 'London'
```

Can anybody tell me how it can be done in ASP.NET C#?

Comment: show your code please...

Comment: Your questions is already answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758260/how-to-display-datagridview-vertically

Comment: how you get data i mean using dataset or list?

Comment: Do you want to transpose in SQL or c#? If it is the former the question has been answered here about 10,000 times (Search "SQL Pivot rows to columns", or similar) if it is the former the link above answers your question.

Comment: seeing as you mention ASP .Net 

is this not a html / css solution

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HumanDto humanDto = new HumanDto();
        List<Human> humans = new List<Human>();
        humans.Add(new Human(){city = "London", id = 1});
        humans.Add(new Human() { city = "London2", id = 2 });
        humans.Add(new Human() { city = "London3", id = 3 });
        humans.Add(new Human() { city = "London4", id = 4 });

        humans.ForEach(e => humanDto.Add(e.city, e.id));
    }
}

public class Human
{
    public Int32 id { get; set; }
    public String city { get; set; }
}
public class HumanDto
{
    public List<Int32> Ids { get; set; }
    public List<String> Cities { get; set; }
    public HumanDto()
    {
        Ids = new List<int>();
        Cities = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Add(String city, Int32 Id)
    {
        Ids.Add(Id);
        Cities.Add(city);
    }
}
```