# how to convert DataGridView Columns from vertical to Horizontal

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I will convert DataGridView Columns from vertical to Horizontal 
for example attached image
please help me

[DataGridView  of Horizontal ]

for see example click on link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy37E.png

Comment: This is 
similar question to your question. please refer it


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758260/how-to-display-datagridview-vertically

Comment: i will convert columns from vertical to horizontal according to this image : http://i.stack.imgur.com/xy37E.png

Answer (score 0):

Use Pivot in sql server to conert column to rows.

Comment: i know this method.i need to DataGridView horizontal for winform in C#